# from flask, how to send the matplotlib plot image to html?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask

In `flask`, how can I make the image saved from `plt` in `matplotlib` show up on a webpage? The below python code creates a plot and saves it as a `.png` image. The HTML file also follows. When I ran it I ended up with the error saying:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType.
```

Anyone who can help me please show me what to do.

```
@app.route('/images/<air_quality>')
def images(air_quality):
    return render_template("displaygraph.html", title=air_quality)

@app.route('/fig/<air_quality>')
def fig(air_quality):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from io import BytesIO

    img = BytesIO()
    pm10 = np.array(['23', '45', '56', '12'])
    pm25 = np.array(['34', '56', '59', '34'])
    dates = np.array(['2017-12-20', '2017-12-21', '2017-12-22', '2017-12-23'])

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), dpi=100, facecolor='1.0')
    plt.title("GangNam", fontsize=20)
    plt.plot_date(dates, pm10, 'rs--', label='pm10')
    plt.plot_date(dates, pm25, 'gs--', label='pm25')
    plt.legend()
    img = plt.savefig('img.png')
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

I do not how to display HTML file here. But the file has this inside the `img` tag:

```
src="{{url_for('fig', air_quality = title)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save pylab figure into in-memory file like `BytesIO`(py3), `StringIO`(py2).

```
plt.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)

response=make_response(img.getvalue())
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
img.close()
return response
```

Comment: @BdginMan Would you pls. fix my codes so that I can figure out how to run it?

Comment: I did but the errors broke out like  TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a '_io.BytesIO' object but received a 'bytes'